# Python function for prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I want to write a function that returns the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number. Function count_primes(100) should return 25

I have written a code which gives 23 instead of 25. The function skips 41 and 71 while counting all other prime numbers in between 1 and 100. Can anyone explain why my code is skipping 41 and 71. My Code is

```
import math
def count_primes(num):
    current_number = 4
    number_of_prime = 2
    while current_number <= num:
        is_prime = True
        if current_number%2==0:
            is_prime = False
            current_number += 1
            continue
        else:
            limit = math.ceil(current_number ** 0.5)+1
            for i in range(3, limit, 2):
                if current_number%i==0:
                    is_prime = False
                    current_number += 1
                    continue
        if is_prime == True:
            print(current_number)
            number_of_prime += 1
        current_number += 1
    return number_of_prime
count_primes(100)
```

I have a written another function which works fine. I just want to know why this code skips 41 and 71 only.

Comment: please explain what you do in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your inner loop:

```
for i in range(3, limit, 2):
    if current_number%i==0:
        is_prime = False
        current_number += 1
        continue
```

The `continue` statement here only continues the inner loop, not the outer one. That means whenever you test a composite number, it increments `current_number` but it doesn't go back to testing divisibility by 2.

For example, in the iteration of the outer loop that starts with `current_number == 39`, the code finds that it is divisible by 3, so it increments `current_number` to 40 and continues the inner loop, not the outer one. So it tests 40 for divisibility by 5, but not by 3. And since 40 is divisible by 5, it goes on to test 41 for divisibility by 7. Of course 41 is not divisible by 7, but `is_prime` is still `False` from back when the code found that 39 is divisible by 3, so 41 doesn't get printed.

This is a rather peculiar combination of circumstances that only happens to affect 41 and 71 in the range you're testing, because they follow sequences of several reasonably large composite numbers, namely 39,40 and 69,70.

I would suggest going through the exercise of working this out yourself: put print statements where you test for divisibility and you'll see what happens clearly. For example:

```
print('testing {} for divisibility by 2: {}'.format(current_number, current_number % 2 == 0))
if current_number%2==0:
    is_prime = False
    ...
```

and later on

```
print('testing {} for divisibility by {}: {}'.format(current_number, i, current_number % i == 0))
if current_number%i==0:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code and added comment:

```
import math
def count_primes(num):
    current_number = 4
    number_of_prime = 2
    while current_number <= num:
        is_prime = True
        if current_number%2==0:
            is_prime = False
            current_number += 1
            continue
        else:
            limit = math.ceil(current_number ** 0.5)+1
            for i in range(3, limit, 2):
                if current_number%i==0:
                    is_prime = False
                    #current_number += 1 #first increment
                    continue
                    #This continue statement does not skip the next lines (after the for loop) so you increment current_number twice
        if is_prime == True:
            print(current_number)
            number_of_prime += 1
        current_number += 1 #second increment
    return number_of_prime
count_primes(100)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do a very good job of explaining why the code in the question didn't work.

Comment: Your Code works fine. But I wanted to know why it only skips 41 and 71.

Comment: @DavidZ This question was unanswered and I didn't have time to explain more. I think that comments inside the code gives good clues on the problem here.

Comment: @ParthoDas the updates I've made should have helped you to find why it skips 41 and 71. Anyways DavidZ gave you all you need