# What can I do to add a list and sort out all the prime numbers in the list? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, primes

I am creating a program that

- accepts an inputted list
- finds all the prime numbers and only displays them.

I tried many different methods, many derived from existing prime filters, but they have hardcoded lists rather user-inputted ones.

I just can't seem to get a filter working with inputting a list, then filtering the prime numbers.

```
my_list = input("Please type a list")

list(my_list)

prime=[]
for i in my_list:
    c=0
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i%j==0:
            c+=1
    if c==1:
        prime.append(i)
return (prime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get input, you're getting a string. You can't cast a string to a list immediately. Maybe you can request the user to use a separator between the numbers then use split method and cast strings to integers like this:

```
my_list = input("Please enter the list of numbers and use space seperator")

s_list = my_list.split()

cast_list = [int(num) for num in s_list]
```

Then, you can work on your prime number task based on your preferred algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your c variable is for, current_number? Your loop returns `'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` for me. I have used len(my_list) to get the length for the loop.

range() defines as `range(start, stop, step)` - learn [more](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) - it accepts integers and parameters are partially optional.

I copied the code from https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+find+prime+numbers+in+list+python

```
my_list = input("Please type a list")

primes = []

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):

    for j in range(2, int(i ** 0.5) + 1):
        if i%j == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes.append(i)

print(primes)
```

More helpful resources from SO: [Python function for prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913954/python-function-for-prime-number)

I hope this helps.

Comment: OK, so my code was a bunch of other codes morphed together and the original one I tried basing off of was lost in the process. Unfortunately, your code did not manage to work.

The original code I based off of was like this:
```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
prime = []
count = 0
for num in list:
     count=0
     for i in range (1, num+1):
              if num%i==0:
                         count += 1
      if count == 2:
               prime.append(num)
print(prime)
```
I want a user inputted list.